# AngularJs handling browser back button and forward button

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a login page using angularjs and html5 .Now when the I give the credentials in the login page it is directed to a new page using angular routing.When I press the sign out button it will navigate back to the login page.Now when I press the forward browser button without giving the credentials it should not open the same page but it should load some other page like session time out or some error page.How can I handle this using AngularJs?

Comment: I'd suggest researching on $rootScope, event emitting and broadcasting. You would want to see if the session has expired before proceeding to next page, or allow it depending on condition that you will setup. Take a look at the post here: https://medium.com/@mattlanham/authentication-with-angularjs-4e927af3a15f#.iwwzsh26t

Comment: plz provide your code . up till now what you tryed...?

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep logout and login in routing try following codes-

```
windows.location.replace=('logout_url')
//Try this if above doesn't work
      windows.location=('logout_url')
```